# bash search for string in each line of file and cp that line

Tags: bash, shell

Im using while loop

```
while read line; do 
echo $line  done < FILE
```

I need modify to search through line in file and once line include $string = test 
i need this line to be copied to output file 
any tips to do it

Comment: Why don't you just use `grep`?

Comment: BTW, `done` has to be a separate statement, not on the same line as `echo`.

Comment: grep -F didnot help me out , let say i wana grep for word test and each line include test i want it to be append to output , i used grep -F file.txt "test" >> output

Comment: You have the arguments to `grep` in the wrong order. The search string comes first, then the filename.

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -F 'test' input_file > output_file
```

Comment: Of course, what he was really trying to do is   grep -F 'test' input_file> output_file;    The business about $string= is a red herring ;)